# how to create new inlinekeyboard when i click old inlinebutton, not replacing

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

i am new to python-telegram bot, I would like to create a new inline keyboard when i press the old inline keyboard without replacing the old one.
I used "editMessageText" to handle the callback query.but it only replaces the inlinekeyboard with "reply_markup",But I want to create a new inlinekeyboard.
How to solve this problem? I searched manytimes in stack overflow.But I couldnot find the solution still now?
Please help me to solve the problem!.My image is

## This is my start(CommandHandler)

```
def start(bot, update):
    bot.sendChatAction(update.message.chat_id, action=ChatAction.TYPING)
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=Message.CLAIM,parse_mode='html')
    reply_markup = telegram.InlineKeyboardMarkup([[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Check New Model",callback_data="New Model")],
                                                [telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Reasses my Insurance",callback_data="Reasses")],
                                                [telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("File a Claim",callback_data="claim")]])

    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Choose the above one?", reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

## This is my Callback Handler

```
def callback(bot,update):
   query=update.callback_query
   if query.data=="claim":


       reply_markup = telegram.InlineKeyboardMarkup([[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Vehicle",callback_data="vehicle")],
                                                    [telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Personal Accident",callback_data="accident")],
                                                    [telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Other",callback_data="other")]])
       bot.editMessageText(
                message_id = update.callback_query.message.message_id,
                chat_id = update.callback_query.message.chat.id,
                text = "Choose the one below",
                reply_markup=reply_markup
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

As per it's name, `bot.edit_message_text` is for editing the text of the message. You need to use `bot.edit_message_reply_markup` ([docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.bot.html?highlight=reply_markup#telegram.Bot.edit_message_reply_markup)).

And if you want to add some buttons to the existing keyboard (if I understood your question), just include it in the edit:

```
reply_markup = telegram.InlineKeyboardMarkup([
[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Check New Model",callback_data="New Model")],
[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Reasses my Insurance",callback_data="Reasses")],
[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("File a Claim",callback_data="claim")],[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Vehicle",callback_data="vehicle")],[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Personal Accident",callback_data="accident")],
[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Other",callback_data="other")]
])
```